# SEQUENCE in DB2

Tags: database, timestamp, db2, sequence

I need to create a sequence in DB2 from the TIMESTAMP, example: today is 08/25/2022 so the sequence must be:

```
082520221
082529222
082520223
082520224
```

And when the server changes the date at midnight to 08/26/2022 the sequence will change to:

```
082620221
082620222
082620223
082620224
```

I can also use functions
Version 7 Release 3

Comment: What would be the next to `082520229` value?

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Comment: What would be the next to 082520229 value?
0825202210
0825202211
0825202212...

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?
Version 7 Release 3

Comment: What's the reason of such a strange generation of non-consecutive numbers? Does the following work for you? `SELECT BIGINT (TO_CHAR (TS, 'MMDDYYYYHH24MISSFF6')) FROM (VALUES TIMESTAMP (GENERATE_UNIQUE())) T (TS)`. If not, then why?

Comment: How do you create that inside a function so I can call it ?

Comment: Whats the "24MISSFF6"? Can you explain it please

Comment: The `Generate_unique` function return unique binary value, which may be converted to a timestamp. The timestamp value is formatted to a string representation, which may be converted finally to a bigint value. So you finally get a number with the same higher digits corresponding to the current date. As for format - look at the documentation. HH24 - hours in 24 format, MI - minutes, SS seconds, FF6 - fraction of second. Your function would consist of this single statement in the RETURN clause. It's still unclear why you don't use some ordinal sequence object for this...

Comment: What platform?  Version 7 release 3 could be a relatively current version of  Db2 for IBM i or a really old version of Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion you can create a CTE that has rows containing values in sequence and from there just contact the date and the sequence value.

For example; "MYSEQUENCE" is a CTE containing 2 columns (value, maxvalue) and 100 rows where "value" is 1 to 100;

```
with MYSEQUENCE (VALUE, MAXVALUE) as (
        select *
            from (values(1,100))
        union all
        select VALUE + 1, MAXVALUE
          from MYSEQUENCE
         where VALUE + 1 <= MAXVALUE)
         
    select VARCHAR_FORMAT(current timestamp, 'MMDDYYYY') || VALUE
        from MYSEQUENCE
```

Results;

```
083120221
083120222
083120223
083120224
083120225
083120226
083120227
083120228
083120229
0831202210
0831202211
0831202212
0831202213
0831202214
0831202215
0831202216
0831202217
0831202218
0831202219
0831202220
0831202221
...
```